# Symfony deployment using Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

It's my first time deploying a Symfony app with Heroku. I tried pushing from GitHub, and I get the following error:

```
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "/tmp/build_7bbd75b5/.env" environment file. in /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:557
       !!  Stack trace:
       !!  #0 /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(105): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad()
       !!  #1 /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(148): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv()
       !!  #2 /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/vendor/symfony/runtime/SymfonyRuntime.php(107): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->bootEnv()
       !!  #3 /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(17): Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime->__construct()
       !!  #4 /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/bin/console(11): require_once('...')
       !!  #5 {main}
       !!    thrown in /tmp/build_7bbd75b5/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 557
       !!
```

Following this, I have a dependancy install issue, it looks like it can't install Composer, it might be linked to the previous issue though, I'm not sure.

It seems Heroku can't access my .env file, does it have anything to do with it not being indexed on Github for security purposes? How do I fix this issue? Thank you!

edit: added code:

```
public function loadEnv(string $path, string $envKey = null, string $defaultEnv = 'dev', array $testEnvs = ['test'], bool $overrideExistingVars = false): void
    {
        $k = $envKey ?? $this->envKey;

        if (is_file($path) || !is_file($p = "$path.dist")) {
            $this->doLoad($overrideExistingVars, [$path]);
        } else {
            $this->doLoad($overrideExistingVars, [$p]);
        }

        if (null === $env = $_SERVER[$k] ?? $_ENV[$k] ?? null) {
            $this->populate([$k => $env = $defaultEnv], $overrideExistingVars);
        }

        if (!\in_array($env, $testEnvs, true) && is_file($p = "$path.local")) {
            $this->doLoad($overrideExistingVars, [$p]);
            $env = $_SERVER[$k] ?? $_ENV[$k] ?? $env;
        }

        if ('local' === $env) {
            return;
        }

        if (is_file($p = "$path.$env")) {
            $this->doLoad($overrideExistingVars, [$p]);
        }

        if (is_file($p = "$path.$env.local")) {
            $this->doLoad($overrideExistingVars, [$p]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads env vars from .env.local.php if the file exists or from the other .env files otherwise.
     *
     * This method also configures the APP_DEBUG env var according to the current APP_ENV.
     *
     * See method loadEnv() for rules related to .env files.
     */
    public function bootEnv(string $path, string $defaultEnv = 'dev', array $testEnvs = ['test'], bool $overrideExistingVars = false): void
    {
        $p = $path.'.local.php';
        $env = is_file($p) ? include $p : null;
        $k = $this->envKey;

        if (\is_array($env) && ($overrideExistingVars || !isset($env[$k]) || ($_SERVER[$k] ?? $_ENV[$k] ?? $env[$k]) === $env[$k])) {
            $this->populate($env, $overrideExistingVars);
        } else {
            $this->loadEnv($path, $k, $defaultEnv, $testEnvs, $overrideExistingVars);
        }

        $_SERVER += $_ENV;

        $k = $this->debugKey;
        $debug = $_SERVER[$k] ?? !\in_array($_SERVER[$this->envKey], $this->prodEnvs, true);
        $_SERVER[$k] = $_ENV[$k] = (int) $debug || (!\is_bool($debug) && filter_var($debug, \FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) ? '1' : '0';
    }
```

Comment: Your `.env` file _shouldn't_ be used on Heroku. If you are doing something to explicitly require it, you're doing it wrong. Please show the code where you try to read `.env`.

Comment: I didn't change anything and just tried pushing from my main branch to Heroku, didn't change any code or anything. Should I post the code from vendor/symfony/dotenv?

Comment: You should post whatever part of your code assumes a file called `.env` exists. It should gracefully continue if that file is missing, but at the moment it's blowing up.

Comment: I added what seems to be the issue in /vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php

Comment: Hrm, [apparently Symfony requires a `.env` file by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60252339/354577). That seems like a bad decision to me, but as the answer to that question says you can change the behaviour if you want. I suggest you change your `bootstrap.php` such that it catches the exception when a `.env` file is not found. Then you won't have to commit it.

Comment: In symfony the .env file should be a template. No actual sensitive information should be added to that file and it is usually committed to the repo. If you want to override default env from the .env template file, you should use a .env.local file or actual environment variables